# Two universes are "colliding" and alien "engineers" are going to stop it

Tags: story-identification

I hope somebody can help me with this.

- I read this book like 15 years ago which places it before the year 2000.
- The main plot of the book is that 2 universes (ours and another one?) are "colliding"
- Some humans are taken by alien "***engineers***" (I think that was their name) to their world in order to help to find a solution to the collision problem.

Comment: This seems very broad indeed. Can you offer any more info about the characters, events?

Comment: The OP has [confirmed in a comment](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/78914/two-universes-are-colliding-and-alien-engineers-are-going-to-stop-it/78917#comment165627_78917) that this was answered.

Answer (score 8):

This is Clifford Simak's "[Cosmic Engineers](http://gnomepress.me/2009/09/19/review-cosmic-engineers/)".

> Our band of three make it to Pluto where they engage the assistance of
>   a genius scientist and a gung-ho spaceman.  Contact is established
>   with the mysterious message-senders and our party finishes up at the
>   edge of the universe where the ‘cosmic engineers’ enlist their help to
>   stop two universes colliding. Which of course they do, thereby saving
>   each from total annihilation.

[image]

Comment: thx!thx!thx!Looking now at the reviews of the book i see people didn't like it very much,i will read it again and see if i find the book like at 15 years.thank you again!

Comment: @milka you should mark the answer as "accepted" (the tick near the punctuation).

Comment: @Sjuan: the... "punctuation"?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit - http://www.reactiongifs.com/r/2013/08/air-quotes.gif

Comment: This here question and [this new one](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/96515/a-book-title-with-a-telepathic-woman-awakened-after-a-few-hundred-years) are a perfect example of two completely disjoint story-id questions with the same answer. No way anyone could tell from the questions that they're describing the same book.

Comment: @user14111 - Because only one is marked as accepted they're in no danger of being closed as dupes.