# A book with a telepathic woman awakened after a few hundred years

Tags: story-identification, books, telepathy

I'm trying to remember a book title, with a telepathic woman. She was sleeping in some kind of stasis, locked for years in a sort of capsule in space. Her consciousness was preserved, so she had to do something in the meanwhile so that when she was awakened by an space explorer or something like that she already gained a telepathic skill.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**I'm trying to remember a book title, with a telepathic woman.**

That's [*Cosmic Engineers*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?11453) by [Clifford D. Simak](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/ea.cgi?55) (rhymes with *gimmick*), which was also the answer to [this old question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/78914/two-universes-are-colliding-and-alien-engineers-are-going-to-stop-it). It was originally published as a serial in the [February](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?57455+c), [March](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?57560+c), and [April, 1939](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?57377+c) issues of *Astounding Science-Fiction*, available at the Internet Archive ([[1](https://archive.org/stream/Astounding_v22n06_1939-02#page/n43/mode/2up)], [[2](https://archive.org/stream/Astounding_v23n01_1939-03_frankenscan#page/n55/mode/2up)], [[3](https://archive.org/stream/Astounding_v23n02_1939-04#page/n115/mode/2up)]). Do you recognize any of [these covers](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/titlecovers.cgi?11453)? The novel has its own [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosmic_Engineers). Here is a [review](http://gnomepress.me/2009/09/19/review-cosmic-engineers/).

**She was sleeping in some kind of stasis,**

> Her speech was broken. Her tongue and lips refused to work the way they should, but he understood what she tried to say.
>
> "Yes, I'm all right." She lay quietly on the table. "What year is this?" she asked.
>
> "It's 6948," he told her.
>
> Her eyes widened and she looked at him with a startled glance. "Almost a thousand years," she said. "You are sure of the year?"
>
> He nodded. "That is about the only thing that I am really sure of."
>
> "How is that?"
>
> "Why, finding you here," said Gary, "and reviving you again. I still don't believe it happened."

**locked for years in a sort of capsule in space.**

> "They condemned me to space," she said. "They put me in that shell you found me in and a war cruiser towed it out to Pluto's orbit and cut it loose. It was an old condemned craft, its machinery outmoded. They ripped out the rockets and turned it into a prison for me."

**Her consciousness was preserved, so she had to do something in the meanwhile so that when she was awakened by an space explorer or something like that she already gained a telepathic skill.**

> "I knew it would be a gamble," she said. "I knew he intended that I should take that gamble. Maybe he had a wild scheme of coming out and hunting for me. Maybe something happened and he couldn't come. Maybe he tried and failed. Maybe the war . . . got him. But he had given me a chance, a desperate chance to beat the fate the military court had set for me. I removed the steel partition in the engine room to make the tank. That took many weeks. I etched the copper plate. I went outside on the shell and etched the lines beside the lock. I'm afraid that wasn't a very good job."
>
> "And then," said Herb, "you put yourself to sleep."
>
> "Not exactly sleep," she said. "Because my brain still worked. I thought and thought, for almost a thousand years. My mind set up problems and worked them out. I developed a flair for pure deduction, since my mind was the only thing left for me to work with. I believe I even developed telepathic powers."

Of course there's much more to the story: aliens, robots, colliding universes, etc. Here's the back cover blurb from the  1964 [Paperback Library edition](https://www.isfdb.org/wiki/images/7/78/CSMCNGNRSP1964.jpg):

> **"UPON YOU,
>
> AND YOU ALONE
>
> MUST REST THE FATE
>
> OF THE UNIVERSE.
>
> YOU ARE THE ONLY
>
> ONES TO SAVE IT."**
> Thus spoke the mysterious Cosmic
> Engineers to a small group of human
> beings on the rim of the Solar System.
> Somewhere out there in the vastness
> of the galaxies lurked the greatest
> challenge they would ever face--the
> catastrophic fury of the Hellhounds of
> Space. Promptly, courageously the
> earthlings boarded their galactic
> spaceships and journeyed out far be-
> yond uncharted stars, plunging into
> dangers too awful to even contemplate.

Comment: +1 for giving the pronunciation, I never know how his name was pronounced.

Comment: @OrganicMarble Thanks. I wish I knew an authoritative source for that pronunciation. I guess the original old-country pronunciation (some kind of Slavic I suppose) would be "see mack". As a kid I used to say "sigh mack" until I was corrected by somebody I believed would know what he was talking about. (Now, if anybody wants to know how [John Sladek](http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/ea.cgi?1036) pronounced his last name, I have it FTHM that it rhymes with "paddock".)

Comment: Thanks for this answer; it came up as a suggestion while I was typing my question, and it's spot on.

Comment: @user14111 necropost here ... but the wikipedia page for Simak cites [this page](https://www.loc.gov/nls/about/organization/standards-guidelines/qrst/#s) to say it's pronounced SIM-ik, agreeing with you.  In addition [this forum post](https://www.sffchronicles.com/threads/549645/page-7) has links to his name being pronounced in recorded radio show adaptations of his stories; presumably he made sure they got it right.

Comment: @RossPresser Thanks!